# in Open CV Sharp, how can I preview a webcam at one resolution and save the image at a higher resolution?

Tags: c#, opencv, webcam-capture

I am creating a web camera capture user control for use in a WPF application.
Previously I was using WPF Media Toolkit for the camera capture.
That works, but the frame rate I am getting from Open CV is better
Also, using Media Toolkit, I haven't been able to save the current frame at high res but I can in Open CV.
My Usercontrol is working well with my Logitech Brio web cam.
Setting the resolution to 1920 x 1080, my frame rate is very good.
When I set it to 3840 x 2160, it is a bit choppy.

What I want to do is view the camera live preview at 1920, bu when I want to capture the current frame, do so at full resolution.
I tried stopping the camera, setting the resolution and restarting, but that takes way too long.
I can’t seem to change the resolution on the fly.

Any ideas?

I was thinking of setting the image source in the capture loop, and setting another image source less often, after changing its size, but I doubt that is a very good solution.

```
   public async Task Start()
        {
            // Never run two parallel tasks for the webcam streaming
            if (_previewTask != null && !_previewTask.IsCompleted)
                return;

            var initializationSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);

            _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            _previewTask = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    // Creation and disposal of this object should be done in the same thread 
                    // because if not it throws disconnectedContext exception

                    if (!videoCapture.Open(CameraDeviceId))
                    {
                        throw new ApplicationException("Cannot connect to camera");
                    }
                    SetResolution();
                    using (frame)
                    {
                        while (!_cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                        {
                            videoCapture.Read(frame);
                            if (!frame.Empty())
                            {
                                // Releases the lock on first not empty frame
                                if (initializationSemaphore != null)
                                    initializationSemaphore.Release();
                                _lastFrame = FlipHorizontally
                                    ? BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(frame.Flip(FlipMode.Y))
                                    : BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(frame);
                                _lastFrame.SetResolution(800, 600);
                                var lastFrameBitmapImage = _lastFrame.ToBitmapSource();
                                lastFrameBitmapImage.Freeze();
                                webcamPreview.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                                       () => webcamPreview.Source = lastFrameBitmapImage);
                            }
                            //  RenderGreenScreenMask(frame, backGroundImage);
                            // 30 FPS
                            await Task.Delay(FrameDelay);
                        }
                    }

                    videoCapture?.Dispose();
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (initializationSemaphore != null)
                        initializationSemaphore.Release();
                }

            }, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);

            // Async initialization to have the possibility to show an animated loader without freezing the GUI
            // The alternative was the long polling. (while !variable) await Task.Delay
            await initializationSemaphore.WaitAsync();
            initializationSemaphore.Dispose();
            initializationSemaphore = null;

            if (_previewTask.IsFaulted)
            {
                // To let the exceptions exit
                await _previewTask;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am not sure whether that is possible at all. To my knowledge you can only open a camera with a single connection and you have to specify the mode. But I know that DirectShow has a preview-mode to open a device. Maybe take some research on that one. Your problem is, that the camera doesnt allow high frame rates with highest resolution, right? So it's not at about too slow rendering but about the bandwidth of the camera itself?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/win32/blob/docs/desktop-src/DirectShow/controlling-a-capture-graph.md I dont know enough about DirectShow, but it looks like they use both at the same time, a preview and a capture stream, where the capture stream will start and stop in demand (in a timed region).